# Timelapse Software on Laptop for Sony a6300 for year long timelapse

Tags: timelapse

I'd like to create a timelapse running for 1 year and chose as a camera the Sony a6300 as it can be easily powered by cable (Instead of getting dummy batteries and so on)

But I cannot find a software for my laptop/computer with which I can run this.
The laptop needs to trigger the camera, optimally change settings on the camera (To adjust for the night) and store the created files.

Can you recommend anything? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The software you can use for example is [Imaging Edge](https://support.d-imaging.sony.co.jp/app/imagingedge/en/)

For your camera it support tethering. [Here is example](https://support.d-imaging.sony.co.jp/app/imagingedge/en/instruction/4_1_connection.php) how to connect your camera.

And [here](https://support.d-imaging.sony.co.jp/app/imagingedge/en/instruction/4_5_remote.php) how to set shooting on interval.

Also few points for consideration:

- Are you sure you will have power all the time? Or power interruption
  will be for less time laptop battery can handle?
- Do you have enough disk space to store all the images?